# cloud.cfg->'manage_etc_hosts' keeps changing my hosts file. But where the host name comes from?

Tags: cloud-init

This is my hosts file:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 v116 v116
127.0.0.1 localhost
The line 127.0.1.1 v116 v116 is causing issues.
```

I know I can disable `manage_etc_hosts` as suggested in the comments.

But where the value `v116 v116` is coming from? Is there any data or value file?

Comment: Is v116 the name of the node you configured in your cloud (openstack?). Look in the tmpl file mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I used grep, there is no mention of "v116" anywhere. 

Can't find where it comes from

Comment: If it is in an openstack environment, you get the info with this command: `curl "http://169.254.169.254/openstack/latest/meta_data.json"`